# what is the apparent size of a 1' object that is 600' away?

Tags: geometry

I am trying to impress US Coast Guard search and rescue experts how small the human head is (say, 1' in size) when the person waving to us is 600' away (roughly 1/10th of a nautical mile.)

When I calculate it, I get a size smaller than this period [ . ] which doesn't track to my own experiences...

1/600 is .02"...

Comment: I get $\ 60\cdot \pi/180\cdot \tan^{-1}(1/600) \approx 5.7\ $ or $5.7$ minutes of arc.

Comment: .02" seen from a distance of 1' seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @Somos how do I convert 5.7 mins of arc to inches?

Comment: @KeithMcClary that's reeeaally small and my own physical experience is that a 1' object, e.g. a human head, appears about as large the bottom of this 'a'...  what I'm trying to do is prove it mathematically...

Comment: From Wikipedia [Apparent diamenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_diameter) "The angular diameter, angular size, apparent diameter, or apparent size is an angular measurement " What is **your** definition of "apparent size"?

Comment: @Somos well, think of it this way.  say I see a car, 15' in length, parked 600' feet away.  If I held up a ruler and "measured" the car's apparent size against the ruler, it would be, e.g. 4"...  that's what I call its apparent size - what it looks like in size at a distance...

Comment: @Somos that's why I am sure that .02 of an inch can't be right.  a ruler couldn't measure something that small - yet I can see the head...

Comment: Okay, **how** did you calculate that 4" from 15' and 600'?

Comment: @Somos no calc - I offered it as an example in response to your question "just what do you mean by 'apparent' size..."  just an example of the thought process.

Comment: So you do't have any way to calculate "appranet size"? You stated in your question "When I calculate it". So, how do you do the calcuation?

Comment: @Somos ah, I see.  here you go - https://www.1790.us/-search-rescuehumanhead.html

Comment: or just using 1' / 600' and converting to inches, which gets a somewhat larger size than the formula embedded in the seamanship article (0.02" v 0.04")

Comment: about 1/5 of the apparent size of moon.

Comment: @USCGAuxVin I just added a couple of words to my answer. The gist is: You know how a $1'$ head looks from $4'$ away. Now I'm saying, that at $600'$ it would look like $2.032mm$ as seen from $4'$ away. Picture looking at the end of a $#2$ pencil lead ($2.20 mm$) from $4'$ away. I thought it would be easier to visualize than so many arc-seconds and such.

Comment: A period at what distance from you? The letter "a" at what distance from you?

Answer (score 0):

The [web page you link to](https://www.1790.us/-search-rescuehumanhead.html) "The Size of an Object at a Distance" has a right triangle that is not labeled correctly. The page states:

> let's make a simple model... Draw a right triangle ABC where A is the position of your eye, B (right angle) is the foot of the object, and C is the top of the object. BC=1 foot, the height of the object.

The accompanying diagram has the length of AB as 1' and BC as 600' which seems to reverse the role of A and C. In any case, the formula used is:

> For $x=600$ this equals $\textrm{arctan}(1/600)/45^\circ = 0.002122$ or about $1/471$ft.

This is based on the following reasoning:

> We need to assume something else, that the apparent height of the object is proportional to angle A, the angle it uses in our field of vision.

Now, it is true that the apparent height of an object is related to the angle it subtends, but clearly, it is not such a simple thing. The calculation apparently takes the angle subtended and divides it by a $45^\circ = \pi/4$ angle. This is a ratio of two angles and it turns out that the ratio of the two angles is $1:471$ and somehow this gets turned into feet. This reasoning only makes sense if we **assume** for convenience, that the object is located **one foot** in front of our eyes. In that case, we don't really need trigonometric functions. It is simply a matter of proportions and similar triangles. To be clear, this calculation is **not** correct but only approximately so. The correct calculation is as follows.

Suppose you place a yardstick upright at eye level and an agreed distance from your eyes, for example one foot. You measure an object using the yeardstick. Now define the apparent size of the object to be its size when it is one foot away from your eyes. Now move the object away at a distance a multiple of one foot away from your eyes and still at eye level. By similar triangles, the apparent size of the object shrinks directly proportionaly to how far it is away. Thus, if it moves twice as far, then it appears half the size when measured using the same yardstick. In the case of interest, the human head is supposed to be one foot high, and at a distance of 600 times as far as the standard distance of one foot, it appears $1/600$th the size which is now $1/600$ foot $= 0.02$ inch. So you are correct about your calculation given the assumption about the meaning of apparent size using one foot as the standard distance.

Here is a brief summary with a formula. Suppose you have an object at eye level a distance $D$ away with vertical height $B$, and another object at eye level a distance $S$ away with vertical height $A$ which **appears** to be the same size as the other object. The triangles formed with your eye and the base and top of the two objects are similar. That implies that the ratios $B/D$ and $A/S$ are equal. Solving the equation gives $\ A = S\ B/D\ $ as the formula for the apparent size of the remote object referred to a local object at distance $S$. Your example distances are $\ S = B = 1\ $foot, and $D = 600\ $foot and thus the apparent head size is  $1/600$ foot $= 0.02$ inch.

**Note carefully** that he Wikipedia article [Angular diameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_diameter)  states

> The **angular diameter**, **angular size**, **apparent diameter**, or **apparent size** is an angular measurement

but it is not really about "apparent size" in our context. The obvious reason is that angles are not linear distances or ratio of distances. For **small** angles and **relative** sizes of distant objects, there is not much difference from using the relative apparent size of distant objects. Still, angular diameter and apparent size are apples and oranges. It is like the difference between an angle and the tangent of the angle defined as a ratio of two lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are looking at a $3'$ ruler from $4'$ away with the base at eye level. Then the top would be $5'$ away and you have a $3,4,5$ triangle with a tangent of $\frac{3}{4}$. Now let's move the the ruler to $600'$ (150 times farther) away. The new tangent would be $\frac{3}{600}$. Now, given the ratio $\frac{3}{4}:\frac{3}{600}$ we can set that it reduces to $1:150$.

Your $1'$ ruler (or head) would now look to be $\frac{1}{150}'=\frac{2}{25}"=2.032mm$ as seen from $4$ away. A #2 pencil lead is $2.20 mm$ for comparison.

BTW: I believe your first answer was correct if you follow the reasoning above with the initial viewing at $1'$ away because you would be increasing the distance by $600$. Now it would look like $0.02"=0.508mm$ as seen from $1'$ away. Think of a $5mm$ mechanical pencil lead.